# Windows is not recognizing my wireless network adapter

Tags: windows, network-adapter

I have a laptop which had Ubuntu on it and working graphics and wireless. 
I just installed a fresh copy of Windows 7. Windows does not recognis my wireless network adapter.

I cannot do any updates or anything hence I don't have access to the Internet.

Also if someone can answer this question, when I installed windows it is all zoomed in exactly like how safe mode would be.

Comment: First things firs, do your computer detect your wireless card as unknown device? Check device manager to confirm. Can you connect pendrives to your pc and use them?

Answer (score 1):

Your computer doesn't automatically have the driver to all wireless cards, but it does have many of them. In the instances where it doesn't, the driver must be retrieved from an outside source.

This is a common experience -- most people solve it by connecting their computer to the router via Ethernet first to download the driver from the manufacturer. Another alternative is to download the driver on another computer and transfer it via USB, like Techie007 said.

Also, you need to get your video drivers as well. Here's a link to help with the former:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626158(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Go to another computer and download your WiFi drivers to a USB drive and then install them to your computer via USB.

Then once your Internet connection is setup you can go get other drivers directly (ie: the one for your display adapter, so you can select a higher resolution).

Comment: Is there another way? Can't I just go to the network controller and select the wireless network adapter and install it?

Comment: Install what?  You need a driver to install...

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you are missing drivers, both correct graphics drivers and drivers for the wireless network card.

Most likely Windows will find the missing drivers itself once you have internet connectivity.

You can get internet connectivity in the following ways:

1. Install the WiFi drivers locally*
2. Use your smartphone with the USB charging cable and enable tethering over USB on the phone.
3. Connect to the internet with a traditional network cable.
4. Same as 3, but use a USB to Ethernet adapter if you don't have an Ethernet port.

*To install the WiFi drivers locally, you need to get them on the PC first. Look them up on the manufacturers website, by the model of your computer. There are several options to get them on a PC without internet:

1. Download to the phone and use the charging cable to connect the phone to the PC, from where you can access the files on the phone.
2. Download to a SD card with the phone, tablet, or another PC, remove the SD card, and plug it into the computer without internet.
3. Download to a USB stick with the phone, tablet, or another PC, then plug the USB stick into the computer without internet.

There are many other ways to move data, but these are probably the ones available to most consumers in this day and age.